# How to run Blender through RDP on Windows Server 2008 R2 - opengl error

Tags: opengl, installation, versions

I want to render my blender project in rdp. But some error has appeared. What is the best solution for this problem? I've spent many hours trying to troubleshoot this problem. 
[image: Blender's error message, and system graphics specs]

Comment: I remember that there were some issues with Remote Desktop accessing OpenGL... try coneccting using VNC.

Comment: GarageFarm.NET had the correct [answer](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/73014/2217). By adding the appropriate DLL to my Blender directory (running on a Windows Azure virtual machine) I was able to get it (v2.78c) to run without a problem. Obviously this isn't going to be speedy by any stretch, but when you're just trying to render a few cubes, it's more than sufficient.

Answer (score 17):

To run Blender on a machine without OpenGl support, you would need to:

1. Download the opengl32.dll or opengl64.dll from this
   link: http://download.blender.org/ftp/sergey/softwaregl/
2. Copy and paste the dll next to your blender.exe (the directory
   would typically be: C:\Program Files\Blender Foundation\Blender)
3. Run Blender

This enables Blender to open with software opengl legacy mode.

Comment: How does this not have more upvotes...

Comment: What is weird about this is that it seems to only be a problem when you *start* Blender from inside of a Remote Desktop Session. If you start Blender *before* you start the Remote Desktop Session and *then* connect the RDS, it actually seems to work just fine. So my question is, if it seems to work just fine when connecting RDS to an existing instance, why even have this detection and limitation at startup?

Comment: I've noticed the same behaviour as swooby did.

Comment: Also, after this, your GUI is going to become super slow, since it will use OpenGL to render the GUI.

Comment: Unfortunately did not work for me. RDP & RTX 2080 Ti on March 10 2020 drivers w/ 64-bit opengl32.dll in Blender 2.8 directory

Comment: But having this file near `blender.exe` makes this error popup when running it locally :)

Answer (score 3):

Sad but simple problem. You and I are in the same boat. Our computers' graphics cards do not support opengl 2.1. (you seem to be using Vmware, so check if your host computer has opengl 2.1 support.)

Anyway 2.77 simply will not run if you do not have opengl 2.1, period. (In most cases it is not worth looking in to updating your drivers, either your hardware supports it or it doesn't.)

The solution (and what I have to do for one machine) is to use [blender 2.76](http://download.blender.org/release/Blender2.76/). That version not only does not have the opengl 2.1 requirement, but overall will run on "older" systems.

Comment: i've tried install blender 2.76b. It said 3d hardware acceleration not found. But i can open blender. thank you for the solution.

Answer (score 2):

I got the same problem with RDP to execute 2.77.
But, it works well with TeamViewer.
https://www.teamviewer.com/
[image]

Comment: Be aware Teamviewer requires purchasing a commercial license for commercial work, but is free for personal use. Alternatives are VNC, Steam Remote Play, Shadow, and more https://alternativeto.net/software/teamviewer/

Answer (score 0):

You can use tscon to disconnect current remote session and launch blender outside remote session.

This is described here: https://support.smartbear.com/testcomplete/docs/testing-with/running/via-rdp/keeping-computer-unlocked.html

only problem is you have to reconnect remote session after blender is started.

1. after disconnection of remote session the terminal stays unlocked so the line
2. Rundll32.exe user32.dll, LockWorkStation locks the workstation after disconnection
3. last line starts blender
4. Put the following lines in a batch file and launch on remote machine as administrator

my start batch:

```
for /f "skip=1 tokens=3" %%s in ('query user %USERNAME%') do (
  %windir%\System32\tscon.exe %%s /dest:console
)

Rundll32.exe user32.dll, LockWorkStation

"C:\Program Files\Blender Foundation\Blender\blender.exe"
```