# Blender via RDP is super slow. Why?

Tags: interface

When I open blender on my old bad laptop, it works smooth. Even if there are hundreds of particles on the scene.

But when I open the same file on the powerful 64-core server via RDP (windows remote desktop), it is freaking slow. Just unbelievably slow. Each click takes 30-40 seconds to react. How can I fix it?

I've tried TeamViewer, but it is not working on the server (stucks on Initializing Display Parameters).

Comment: related: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/50321/how-to-run-blender-through-rdp-on-windows-server-2008-r2-opengl-error andhttps://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/61810/how-to-bypass-opengl-1-2-requirement-for-remote-gpu-rendering

Answer (score 1):

I can confirm the same behavior. In order to get Blender GUI to run on a remote machine I had to place an openGL file in the blender installation folder. I'm currently looking for a solution to this.

Comment: This does not seem like an answer to the question but rather a "me too" post.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I just put All mesa-dist-win 18.2.1 DLLs to "C:\Program Files\Blender Foundation\Blender" and it worked.

This DLL is not very slow.

[using this](https://github.com/pal1000/mesa-dist-win/releases)
https://github.com/pal1000/mesa-dist-win/releases